# How to extract dynamic drop-down forms with iMacros?

Tags: drop-down-menu, vbscript, imacros

I am looking to fill out a dynamic dropdown form with `iMacros`. With a regular form, I am able to loop using VBS successfully and able to extract information based on how I fill out the dropdown form.

However, there is one website that I'm trying to extract from where the option values in field 2 completely changes based on what you select in field 1. (i.e.  `"<option value="">"` changes).

I am having trouble looping this, since the `iMacro function` doesn't work when you use  `#`, `$` or `%` for the `CONTENT` attribute. (I have tried them all).